# Как я могу скрывать и показывать элементы в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть страница с двумя блоками. Хочу реализовать типа "читать далее".
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practice Site</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom_jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <h1>First Block</h1>
        <p>Text of first block <a class="show">Show</a></p>
        <p class="hide-content">Hide content first block <a     
        class="hide">hide</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <h1>Second Block</h1>
        <p>Text of second block <a class="show">Show</a></p>
        <p class="hide-content">Hide content second block <a    
        class="hide">hide</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() { 
$('.show').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).hide();
    $('.hide-content').show(500);
});
$('.hide').on('click', function()
    $('.hide-content').hide(500);
    $('.show').show();
});
});
```

В данный момент, при нажатии на "Show" раскрываются оба блока. Задача в том, чтобы раскрывался .hide-content того блока, в котором нажали show.
Заранее, спасибо)

Comment: Скрывайте принудительно все и показывайте конкретный через `(this).find('.hide-content')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(function() { 
    $('.show').on('click', function() { 
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('.block').find('.hide-content').show(500);
    });
    $('.hide').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.hide-content').hide(500);
        $(this).closest('.block').find('.show').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!